# Execution time between two lines or a function in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, ide

In eclipse, I couldn't find how to get the IDE to display the amount of time it took for a program to execute. I've checked help and googled and I'm not finding anything

I don't want to write startTime,endTime code around each & every line.
Is there any way we can do it in eclipse or through eclipse plugin without writing code.

Comment: subsctractiing end time from begin time... System.nanoTime() or System.currentTimeMillis()...

Comment: You can't do it using your IDE solely.You can connect to Visual VM and track the processing time for each method.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ  This is what I have written in my question,If you read it carefully.
I don't want to write code every time whenever I suspect that this line/function is taking time in execution.

Comment: Use JVisualVM or similar to profile your app.

Comment: @AnkitTripathi,I have connected my tomcat to Visual VM but couldn't figure out how to find processing time for each method ??
Any idea about this ?

Comment: @NamingException,Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441274/how-to-use-visualvm-to-get-the-time-each-function-costs

Answer (score 1):

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();    
// ... the code being measured ...    
long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

Props to: 
[How do I measure time elapsed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java)